# Is the lack of blocklisting support for invalid tokens a serious threat?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have been ramping up on Django Rest Framework and JWT authentication through tutorials that point to `django-rest-framework-jwt` but while researching how to customize JWT validation, realized that there is a newer implementation `django-rest-framework-simplejwt`.

The older `jwt` package does not have a commit since 2017 but `simple-jwt` is actively maintained and developed, and from what I can find, has better security features. It is also the recommended link in the [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

I could not find a relevant post on S/O but I found that `JoelGoh92` in this [git issue](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/430#issuecomment-387763662) summarizes the problem well:

> 1. In most JWT implementations, an access token + a refresh token is returned. Otherwise the other option, if only a single token is
>    desired, is the sliding token approach. With simple-jwt, the jwt can
>    be configured to either of these implementations, whichever is
>    required.
> 2. With the current django-rest-framework-jwt supported by rest-auth, the only approach available is similar to the sliding token approach,
>    except that it has no way to blacklist a previously generated jwt
>    token, e.g. by logout on user end. On the other hand, simple-jwt
>    provides a way to perform this blacklisting of invalid tokens.

I'm curious to know whether the lack of "blocklisting" support for invalid (logged out) tokens is a serious threat and I (DRF JWT community) should migrate to simple-jwt.